# Disable Bootstrap nav item click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 nav as something like "collapsible div" only which holds multiple level menu. but I have an issue with the nav items or its hyperlinks click event and want to disable it so my menu works the way I want.

For sure I've assigned my custom events to the nav items which open the second level but for some reason that doesn't work fine on mobiles.

I even tried javascript:void() for the hyperlinks but I think the click event of bootstrap is assigned to the `<li>`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following to prevent the default link behavior.

```
$( "a" ).click(function(e) { // target any selector
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I did before and as I told above, it seams that the function assigned to the <LI>

Comment: Actually, you said you tried "javascript:void()". Post your code on your question or JSFiddle and let's take a look.

Comment: I found the reason :), I had added a function before to close the collapsed nav when click body or anywhere but the button .. wasn't a bootstrap nav function was me :(

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out!